# FB like Div inside removes hover state in IE when

Tags: html, css, facebook, hover, parent

I have inserted a facebook like button into a div that hides it's self off the screen until you hover over it:

```
<div id="fb">Some text here<br />
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://etc..." data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" data-colorscheme="dark"></div></div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#fb {
    display:block;
    background:url(images/facebook.png) right no-repeat #000;
    color:#FFF;
    height:89px;
    width:280px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    padding-right:22px;
    margin-left:-280px;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-out;
    font-size:10px;
    border:solid 1px #E3D199;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#fb:hover {
    margin-left:0px;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

The problem is that when i mouse over the parent div in internet explorer it rolls out like normal, but as soon as I roll over the facebook like div it returns to the original "off-the-screen" state before i get a chance to clike on the like button...

can anyone help me figure out how to keep my div ON THE SCREEN when i mouse over the like button.

Answer (score 0):

I cant test in IE right now, but you may want to try:

```
#fb {
    display:block;
    background:url(images/facebook.png) right no-repeat #000;
    color:#FFF;
    height:89px;
    width:280px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    padding-right:22px;
    margin-left:-280px;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-out;
       -moz-transition:all .5s ease-out;
         -o-transition:all .5s ease-out;
            transition:all .5s ease-out;
    font-size:10px;
    border:solid 1px #E3D199;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Alex

Comment: it's not the transitions that have the error, there are no transitions in IE anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
<style>    
.zor{z-index:-1;}
</style>

....
<div class="zor">
<div class="fb-like zor" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but that made absolutely no difference.

Comment: ooops! i post NEW solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use javascript, try (has tested) :

```
<script>
function SetMarginLeft(v){
mm = document.getElementById("fb").style;
mm.marginLeft=v;
}
</script>

...
<div id="fb" onMouseOut="SetMarginLeft('-280px');" onMouseOver="SetMarginLeft('0px');">Some text here<br />
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://etc..." data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
</div>
...
```